# HTML Multi-Page Form Issues (page is refreshing)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am having a problem with a multi-page form submission.  The problem is that the page is refreshing when I press the next page button.  I believe it is a return true/false problem, but I don't know where the issue is.  Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var info = [];
        function showinfo() {
            for (i=0; i<info.length; i++) {
                $('#step3 ul').append(
                    $('<li>' + info[i] + '</li>')
                );
            };
        };
        $('#step1_btn').click(function() { 
            $("input").each(function() {
                if (input.type != radio) {
                    info.push(this.name+':'+this.value);
                } else if ($('.radio').is(':checked')) {
                    info.push(this.name+':'+this.value);
                }
            });
            $('#step1').css('display','none');
            $('#step2').css('display','inherit');
            $('#progbar').attr('value',33);
            return false;
        });
        $('#step2_btn').click(function() {
            $("input").each(function() {
                if (input.type != radio) {
                    info.push(this.name+':'+this.value);
                } else if ($('.radio').is(':checked')) {
                    info.push(this.name+':'+this.value);
                }
            });
            $('#step2').css('display','none');
            $('#step3').css('display','inherit');
            $('#progbar').attr('value',66);
            showinfo();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Not sure if that is all you need to see.  If you need to see the html as well, I can provide that.  Thanks in advance for any help you all can give.  I can read javascript fairly well when someone else writes it, but for some reason writing it myself ends up in catastrophe every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
$('#step1_btn').click(function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   // your code here
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  That fixed the refresh it seems.  Now I just gotta go through and fix my code so it actually works.  Hah.